# sonar qube error while integrating with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube5.1

We are trying to integrate SONAR QUBE checks when the developers tries to merge to MAIN branch.

When we try to incorporate the sonar checks as part of check in policy , we get the below error

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Validation of project reactor failed:
o To use the property "sonar.pullrequest.key" and analyze pull requests, Developer Edition or above is required. See https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/branches.html for more information.
o To use the property "sonar.pullrequest.branch" and analyze pull requests, Developer Edition or above is required. See https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/branches.html for more information.
o To use the property "sonar.pullrequest.base" and analyze pull requests, Developer Edition or above is required. See https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/branches.html for more information.
ERROR:
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
15:41:50.483 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
The process 'C:\GITGSROOT\_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.11.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

We are using SONAR community edition. Is this integration not supported by community edition of SONAR QUBE ?

Comment: Does the reply below help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in [Sonar Qube forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-7-2-vsts-plugin-4-3-0-stop-work-with-pull-request/596/2)

> Pull Request support requires at least the developer edition of SonarQube. If you don’t want to analyze your pull requests and keep using the community edition, then simply create a second build definition without any SonarQube task, and use it in your branch strategy to build pull requests.

And also [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.3/PullRequestAnalysis.html)

> Pull Request analysis is available as part of Developer Edition and higher.

So you can't do this with community edition.